PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 20): Holly
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >


Find the hidden holiday message.

@bobble, yikes, sorry. I don’t know why I keep forgetting stuff. Thanks for editing it!

The two images

 are the same size.

If we

 put the second one over the first one, it seems to form six-packs of dots.
 

So we

 interpret the six-packs as braille. Six-packs grouped by a circle are all combined.
 

As noneuclideanisms points out

 the leaves form semaphore patterns.
 


All together the hidden holiday message is

 I WISH YOU A MERRY CHRISTMAS AND A HAPPY NEW YEAR!


rot13(v oryvrir gur yrnirf pna nyfb or vagrecergrq nf frzncuber)

@noneuclideanisms Nice, now it makes more sense. I'll add that in...

Congrats, you got it!

(And I didn’t mean for the “X UN” to be there, I think it was just a random pattern that happened to look like the letters lol)
